# Biblatex error: \DeclareCaseLangs{} undefined

Tags: biblatex

I have multiple documents with bibliographies that do not compile anymore. They all use the `\DeclareCaseLangs` macro to adjust bibliography formatting.

The error is still present without all the custom macros and packages, compilation log prints:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \DeclareCaseLangs
                   {american}
? x
```

Copying the macro definition from `blx-case-latex2e.sty` still leads to an `undefined control sequence`.

A workaround is to comment the language declaration, but this is not acceptable as it destroys the entry formatting in the bibliography.

Here is a M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareCaseLangs{american}


\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

Tested with `TexLive 2020` up to date, `lualatex 1.12.0`  and `pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21`.

Comment: see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1090

Comment: thank you for pointing at that page and to its temporary solution that saves my report!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike points out in the comments, this is a bug in `biblatex` v3.16 (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1090). A fix is being worked on.

The problem is that the case changing code needs to be loaded depending on the document encoding. To avoid load order issues, the document encoding is best detected in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook. But if we only load the case changing code at that point, its commands are undefined in the document preamble.

For now there are two workarounds. The straightforward workaround is to move `\DeclareCaseLangs` to an `\AtBeginDocument` hook (that is guaranteed to be executed after `biblatex`'s `\AtBeginDocument` hook is processed).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\AtBeginDocument[biblatex/declarecaselangs]{%
  \DeclareCaseLangs{american}%
}
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{biblatex/declarecaselangs}{after}{biblatex}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

---

If that level of change to your document preamble is unacceptable, you can try the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\blx@checkencoding
\blx@deferoption@casechanger
\blx@casechange@postload
\let\blx@deferoption@casechanger\relax
\let\blx@casechange@postload\relax
\makeatother

\DeclareCaseLangs{american}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The code between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` executes the relevant parts of the `\AtBeginDocument` that loads the case changing code directly and disables it afterwards. You can then use `\DeclareCaseLangs` as usual after this code block.

**Please do not continue to use this workaround once the fixed version of `biblatex` is released.**

Comment: With the newest latex it is no longer needed to guard the order with a label and  rule: top-level code will always be executed last